# Is a projective $R[G]$-module a projective $R[H]$-module if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, projective-module

I have a ring $R$ of characteristic $0$ and a finite group  $G$. Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$.

> > **Question**: If $M$ is a projective $R[G]$-module where $R[G]$ is the usual group ring then is $M$ also projective as an $R[H]$-module?

This seems easy but I'm having trouble showing that if $M$ is a summand of a free $R[G]$-module then it's also the summand of a free $R[H]$-module.

I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: Are the groups finite? Can you prove that $R[G]$ is a free $R[H]$-module?

Comment: Yes the groups are finite (I've now edited the question). I've tried to prove that but I can't see beyond $R[G]$ being a left $R[H]$-module.

Comment: If $g_1,g_2,\ldots, g_k$ are representative of right cosets of $H$, then won't we get that $R[G]$ is a free left $R[H]$-module with basis $g_1,g_2,\ldots,g_k$?

Comment: Of course you are right. Regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The mentioned assumptions are not necessary. If $R$ is any ring and $H$ is a subgroup of any group $G$, then $R[G]$ is a free $R[H]$-module (both from left and from right). This is basically because $G$ is a free $H$-set. We have $G = \coprod_i H g_i$ for some $g_i \in G$, and hence $R[G] = \bigoplus_i R[H] g_i$.

Since $R[G]$ is a free $R[H]$-module, any free $R[G]$-module restricts to a free $R[H]$-module. Hence, the same holds for projective modules.